# Is there a way to simplify the multi binomial expansion $(x+y)^n (x-y)^m$?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the expression
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&(x + y)^n
(x - y)^m\\
&=
\sum_{k_1=0}^n
\sum_{k_2=0}^m
\binom{n}{k_1}
x^{k_1}
y^{n-k_1}
\binom{m}{k_2}
x^{k_2}
y^{m-k_2}
(-1)^{m-k_2}\\
&=
\sum_{k_1=0}^n
\sum_{k_2=0}^m
\binom{n}{k_1}
\binom{m}{k_2}
x^{k_1+k_2}
y^{n+m-k_1-k_2}
(-1)^{m-k_2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Is there a way to combine the binomial coefficient and write the expression to single summation?

Comment: Not really. You can rewrite, when $m\leq n$ as $(x^2-y^2)^m(x+y)^{n-m},$ and expand that, but you still get a double sum. When $n< m$ substitute $y'=-y$ and you have the the same case, and you get $(x^2-y^2)^{n}(x-y)^{m-n}.$